# What length does '1024**2' signify in GAE Search API TextField docs?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I'm planning to use GAE's Search API for some fulltext string indexing but am unsure of what something in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) means:

> Text Field: A string with maximum length 1024**2 characters.

Comment: It's Python syntax for 1024 squared.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Please make it an answer so I can award you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Python syntax for 1024 squared.  [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

> [the operator] yields its left argument raised to the power of its right argument.